# Private messaging a user

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently using the discord.js library and node.js to make a discord bot with one function - private messaging people.

I would like it so that when a user says something like "/talkto @bob#2301" in a channel, the bot PMs @bob#2301 with a message.

So what I would like to know is... how do I make the bot message a specific user (all I know currently is how to message the author of '/talkto'), and how do I make it so that the bot can find the user it needs to message within the command. (So that /talkto @ryan messages ryan, and /talkto @daniel messages daniel, etc.)

My current (incorrect code) is this:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content == '/talkto') {
        if(messagementions.users) { //It needs to find a user mention in the message
            message.author.send('Hello!'); //It needs to send this message to the mentioned user
    }
}
```

I've read the documentation but I find it hard to understand, I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send` method can be found in a `User` object.. hence why you can use `message.author.send`... message.author refers to the user object of the person sending the message. All you need to do is instead, send to the specified user. Also, using `if(message.content == "/talkto")` means that its only going to run IF the whole message is /talkto. Meaning, you can't have /talkto @me. Use `message.content.startsWith()`.

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("/talkto")) {
        let messageToSend = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ");
        let userToSend = message.mentions.users.first();

        //sending the message
        userToSend.send(messagToSend);
    }
}
```

Example use:

/talkto @wright Hello there this is a dm!